# react hook form with multiple react select as array of objects under the same property name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

Got a specific section in my react hook form with multiple react selects (list of react selects). I'd like them to be under the same property `attributes` such that it's an array of objects inside the react hook form data, though I'm not sure how to go about it using Controller or if it's the right approach

goal for the react hook form data with the multiple react selects all under one property `attributes`

```
{
  "attributes": [
    {
       
       "label": "HAS_LEAVES",
       "value": "YES"
    },
    {
       
       "label": "HAS_TRUNK",
       "value": "NO"
    }
  ]
}
```

however I'm getting this when user interacts with one of the react selects

```
  {
    "HAS_LEAVES":{"label": "Yes", "value": "YES"}
  }
```

react form

```
const selectOptions = [
    { value: "YES", label: "Yes" },
    { value: "NO", label: "No" },
];

const attributes = [
{
       
    "label": "Has Leaves",
    "value": "HAS_LEAVES"
},
{
    
    "label": "Has Trunk",
    "value": "HAS_TRUNK"
}
]

<Controller
    name="attributes"
    control={control}
    render={({ field }) => (
        <ul>
        {selectOptions &&
            selectOptions.length > 0 &&
            attributes.map((attribute, idx) => {
            return (
                <li
                key={idx}
                >
                <span>{attribute.value}</span>
                <span>
                    <Controller
                    name={attribute.value}
                    control={control}
                    render={({ field }) => (
                        <ReactSelect
                        options={selectOptions}
                        {...field}
                        />
                    )}
                    />
                </span>
                </li>
            );
            })}
        </ul>
    )}
/>
```